# Bash script trouble with comparing strings

Tags: bash

I'm trying to compare strings. I get "command not found" error. How do I compare the strings?

Code:

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 STR="Hello World" 
 if [$STR="Hello World"]; then
   echo "passed test"
 else
   echo "didn't pass test"
 fi
```

Output:

```
 test.sh: line 4: [Hello: command not found
 didn't pass test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add spaces. Treat `[[` or `[` as if it's another command like `test` and other builtins. And like other commands, it requires a space after its name. It's also recommended that you use `[[ ]]` over `[ ]` in Bash since `[[ ]]` doesn't split its variables with IFS and do pathname expansions. It also has more features over the other.

```
#!/bin/bash
STR="Hello World"
if [[ $STR = "Hello World" ]]; then
    echo "passed test"
else
    echo "didn't pass test"
fi
```